# child theme - moved files from twentyeleven theme to child them, now not working

Tags: child-theme

I'm trying to create a child theme.

I copied the files from my twenty eleven theme into my twenty eleven child theme folder, and now the webpage displays blank page.

my dashboard settings changed after I created the child theme that is why I decided to copy all files from main theme to child theme folder.

what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just copy all the files it will never work, the reason being that the functions.php file is included from both parent theme & child theme resulting in re-defining of a few functions(which is a php error)

Don't copy the functions.php file, copy all the other files & modify the few lines at the top of style.css as explained in the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)